# How to compile a julia script?

Tags: compilation, julia

I have noticed that the version 0.4.* of julia has a `--compile` option.

Strangely, I cannot find any documentation about it.

I was trying (in Ubuntu), to compile a julia script to an executable LLVM bytecode file. But until here, I failed:

```
julia --compile=yes --output-bc test.bc test.jl
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I also can get this error message:

```
julia --compile=yes --output-bc test.bc test.jl
ERROR: could not open file boot.jl
```

This error does not appear anymore, if I put a `boot.jl` file in the same folder.

How should I do to compile a julia script to an executable/obfuscated bytecode ?

Edit: FYI, my `test.jl` file contains only `print(123)`

Answer (score 19):

Here's an example, from a julia source build on OS X, with /tmp/test.jl as:

```
function foo()
    print(123)
end

precompile(foo, ())
```

And `julia/base/userimg.jl` as `include("/tmp/test.jl")`

Execute the following inside the `julia/base` directory:

```
julia --compile=yes --output-bc test.bc -J ../usr/lib/julia/inference.ji sysimg.jl
```

Then run `llvm-dis test.bc -o test.ll`. Somewhere in the (enormous) image we have the relevant bytecode for the test function:

```
define internal %jl_value_t* @julia_foo_22542() {
top:
  %0 = alloca [4 x %jl_value_t*], align 8, !dbg !51528 
...
```

That said, as of now (Dec. 2015), Julia is not usable for ahead-of-time compilation of stand-alone executables. However, the following may be of interest:

- https://github.com/dhoegh/BuildExecutable.jl (doesn't use `--output-bc`, as yet, but has a nicer user interface and that option would be easy to add)
- https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13677

Comment: Thank you. When I try to execute the `.bc` file. It says that the `main` function is missing. Even if I put a main function in my source file...

Comment: See the link to BuildExecutable. Get something to work with that first, and then modify it to use the `--output-bc` flag.