# Produce a standalone executable from a Julia script?

Tags: julia

Is it possible to create something like a standalone executable from a Julia script?

By standalone I mean that the executable should be able to run in a system (same OS) without Julia.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146968/how-to-compile-a-julia-script

Comment: Probably the most relevant github issue is [8745](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/8745). Haven't tried using it myself.

Answer (score 10):

Many members of the Julia community are interested in this functionality. However, the core Julia developers do not consider this important/urgent ([1](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/list-of-most-desired-features-for-julia-v1-x/4481/25)). Therefore, a few packages have been developed by community members, but they are not very stable/complete ([2](https://github.com/dhoegh/BuildExecutable.jl) & [3](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/static-julia)).

[PackageCompiler](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl) seems to be the best option for compiling a static binary currently available.